# Why does the headers Map contain a List<String> as value and not String?

Tags: spring, http

I saw this code in **package org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest;**

```
public class DefaultSavedRequest implements SavedRequest {
    private final Map<String, List<String>> headers;
}
```

I wonder, why this `Map`'s value is a `List<String>` instead of `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because HTTP allow one header to have multiple values ([Reference](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#field.order))

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
>   name in a message unless either the entire field value for that header
>   field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)] or the
>   header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).
>
> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field
>   name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
>   semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to
>   the combined field value in order, separated by a comma. The order in
>   which header fields with the same field name are received is therefore
>   significant to the interpretation of the combined field value; a proxy
>   MUST NOT change the order of these field values when forwarding a
>   message.

Thinks of it like `Accept` header:

```
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

**Edit**

Here is the code to save header in constructor:

```
public DefaultSavedRequest(HttpServletRequest request, PortResolver portResolver)

Enumeration<String> values = request.getHeaders(name);

while (values.hasMoreElements()) {
    this.addHeader(name, values.nextElement());
}
```

As you can see, for each header name, an enumeration of values is returned, then the program iterate over the values and add them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your answering, but I am still wondering, when the code add values to Map , It does not split multiple values like values.split(",").

Comment: `private void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        List<String> values = (List)this.headers.get(name);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList();
            this.headers.put(name, values);
        }

        ((List)values).add(value);
    }`

Comment: **Please don't use the _old_ and _obsolete_ RFC 2616 as reference anymore.** Consider the RFCs 7230-35 instead.

Comment: It costs a -1? People are so serious nowaday huh.